# How to sort objects by related field?

Tags: django, django-models

I have three models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name', blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
    [...]

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=u'Name', blank=True, null=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True, related_name='cats',verbose_name=u'Categories')
    [...]

class Positions(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    position = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=u'Position in category', default = 0)
    [...]
```

And I want to get items from specified category but ordered by position (from Positions).
Whether it can be done in a query, like:

```
items = Items.objects.filter([...]).order_by(??)
```

Or do I need to add a loop:

```
items = Items.objects.filter([...])
for item in items:
    ???
```

How to do it well?

(I have yet to figure out that if there is no position entry for item in table positions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fully explained [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
Item.objects.filter(...).order_by('positions__position')
```

Comment: The problem here is that Item may have more then one Positions objects, so with such filters there is a possibility of getting duplicates. The filter should be like this `Item.object.filter(positions__category=category).order_by('positions__position')` and Item.categories looks redundant here. Maybe you need also to read this doc "Extra fields on many-to-many relationships" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany